# PyBluez for Windows 10?

Tags: python, sockets, bluetooth, pybluez

I'm trying to run a server - client application using PyBluez (0.23) with Python (3.9) but I can't make it work. I've been reading comments from users that mention that PyBluez has no support for windows 10. Is this true? If so, the only alternative for developing a Bluetooth application on Windows is using Windows Sockets?

Answer (score 0):

You can make PyBluez work on windows 10! It is discribed in detail here:
https://github.com/pybluez/pybluez/blob/master/docs/install.rst
Please be aware on the Windows Dependencies which are also discribed in the install document.